# Is the screen size (e.g. 4" iPhone size) exact?

Tags: ios, cgpoint

I am trying to calculate the physical size of a shape (diameter of a circle) on an iPod touch.
According to the apple website, the screen size is 4" and the aspect ratio is 16/9. Using pythagoras and taking into account the relative size (CG points). I should be able to calculate the physical dot size.
However it always seems to be just a tiny bit out. E.g. instead of a dot size of 1" according to my ruler it will be 1.1"

Unless I am making an incorrect assumption in above. I feel like the only source of error could be due to the constants: incorrect screen size, incorrect aspect ratio or rounding error

Comment: Did you measure the screen to verify it is 4"?

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from wikipedia:

> The display of the iPhone 4 is manufactured by LG under an exclusive contract with Apple. It features an LED backlit TFT LCD capacitive touchscreen with a pixel density of 326 pixels per inch (ppi) on a 3.5 in (8.9 cm) (diagonally measured), 960×640 display. Each pixel is 78 micrometers in width.

There could be many factors, pixel pitch or some other. Don't break it down from the device size. Instead use the size of the pixels, including any pitch between them and multiply up.

There's a library [here](https://github.com/marchv/UIScreenExtension) you might find useful for different devices to get this information, I haven't used it but it looks recent and useful.

Comment: I am the creator of the library you reference to and I can confirm it is maintained. Thanks for linking to it :)